# Website shows different font size even if it was set global

Tags: css, font-size

I have two sites on which the font is set by

```
* {
    font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
}
```

Since the `font-size` is not specified, the browser use his standard values for each element. But if I set the size to `0.9em` the size is really small. The output of `window.getComputedStyle(element).fontSize` also shows different `px` values. If I set `font-size: 13px` the size is everywhere the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I set the size to 0.9em the size is really small.

Yes, it is a relative size.

The `body` becomes 90% of the font size of the `html`.

A `section` inside the `body` becomes 90% of the `body` (so 81% of the `html`).

A `p` inside the `section` becomes 90% of the `section` (so 72.9% of the `html`)

And so on.

> If I set font-size: 13px the size is everywhere the same.

Absolute units do not vary based on the font size of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

This explanation is summarized from the site [Css Font Size](https://www.mediaevent.de/css/font-size.html)

The reason for this is the fact, that `px` is not relative to other elements. `%` and `em` instead are relative to their parent which results in the following effect: 
[image]
Since `100% = 1em` the two units can almost (see [% vs em](https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent)) be used analogously.

One solution is to use `rem`, which acts similar to `em` but does not inherent the value from the parent.
An other is to set a default size for the main element e.g. `body` and then set the font-size relative to the parent for all elements.